# Concrete example showing that monads are not closed under composition (with proof)?

Tags: haskell, monads, composition, proof

It is well-known that applicative functors are closed under composition but monads are not.  However, I have been having trouble finding a concrete counterexample showing that monads do not always compose.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7040998/305559) gives `[String -> a]` as an example of a non-monad.  After playing around with it for a bit, I believe it intuitively, but that answer just says "join cannot be implemented" without really giving any justification.  I would like something more formal.  Of course there are lots of functions with type `[String -> [String -> a]] -> [String -> a]`; one must show that any such function necessarily does not satisfy the monad laws.

Any example (with accompanying proof) will do; I am not necessarily looking for a proof of the above example in particular.

Comment: The closest I can find is the appendix of http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/pubs/RR-1004.pdf, which shows that under a lot of simplifying assumptions, it is impossible to write `join` for the composition of two monads *in general*.  But this does not lead to any *concrete* examples.

Comment: You may get better answers to this question on cs.stackexchange.com, the new Computer Science Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding, but I think the question could be more precisely defined. When you say "composing" two monads, do you mean simply composing the type constructors? And when the result "is not a monad", does this mean that a monad instance of that type construcor cannot be written? And, if a monad instance for the composed type constructor can be written, does it have to bear any relation to the instances of the two factor monads, or can it be totally unrelated?

Comment: Yes, I mean composing the type constructors; "not a monad" means a valid (lawful) monad instance cannot be written; and I don't care whether the instance for the composition has any relation to the instances of the factors.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Consider this monad which is isomorphic to the `(Bool ->)` monad:

```
data Pair a = P a a

instance Functor Pair where
  fmap f (P x y) = P (f x) (f y)

instance Monad Pair where
  return x = P x x
  P a b >>= f = P x y
    where P x _ = f a
          P _ y = f b
```

and compose it with the `Maybe` monad:

```
newtype Bad a = B (Maybe (Pair a))
```

I claim that `Bad` cannot be a monad.

---

**Partial proof:**

There's only one way to define `fmap` that satisfies `fmap id = id`:

```
instance Functor Bad where
    fmap f (B x) = B $ fmap (fmap f) x
```

Recall the monad laws:

```
(1) join (return x) = x 
(2) join (fmap return x) = x
(3) join (join x) = join (fmap join x)
```

For the definition of `return x`, we have two choices: `B Nothing` or `B (Just (P x x))`. It's clear that in order to have any hope of returning `x` from (1) and (2), we can't throw away `x`, so we have to pick the second option.

```
return' :: a -> Bad a
return' x = B (Just (P x x))
```

That leaves `join`. Since there are only a few possible inputs, we can make a case for each:

```
join :: Bad (Bad a) -> Bad a
(A) join (B Nothing) = ???
(B) join (B (Just (P (B Nothing)          (B Nothing))))          = ???
(C) join (B (Just (P (B (Just (P x1 x2))) (B Nothing))))          = ???
(D) join (B (Just (P (B Nothing)          (B (Just (P x1 x2)))))) = ???
(E) join (B (Just (P (B (Just (P x1 x2))) (B (Just (P x3 x4)))))) = ???
```

Since the output has type `Bad a`, the only options are `B Nothing` or `B (Just (P y1 y2))` where `y1`, `y2` have to be chosen from `x1 ... x4`.

In cases (A) and (B), we have no values of type `a`, so we're forced to return `B Nothing` in both cases.

Case (E) is determined by the (1) and (2) monad laws:

```
-- apply (1) to (B (Just (P y1 y2)))
join (return' (B (Just (P y1 y2))))
= -- using our definition of return'
join (B (Just (P (B (Just (P y1 y2))) (B (Just (P y1 y2))))))
= -- from (1) this should equal
B (Just (P y1 y2))
```

In order to return `B (Just (P y1 y2))` in case (E), this means we must pick `y1` from either `x1` or `x3`,
and `y2` from either `x2` or `x4`.

```
-- apply (2) to (B (Just (P y1 y2)))
join (fmap return' (B (Just (P y1 y2))))
= -- def of fmap
join (B (Just (P (return y1) (return y2))))
= -- def of return
join (B (Just (P (B (Just (P y1 y1))) (B (Just (P y2 y2))))))
= -- from (2) this should equal
B (Just (P y1 y2))
```

Likewise, this says that we must pick `y1` from either `x1` or `x2`, and `y2` from either `x3` or `x4`. Combining the two,
we determine that the right hand side of (E) must be `B (Just (P x1 x4))`.

So far it's all good, but the problem comes when you try to fill in the right hand sides for (C) and (D).

There are 5 possible right hand sides for each, and none of the combinations work. I don't have a nice argument for this yet, but I do have a program that exhaustively tests all the combinations:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad (guard)

data Pair a = P a a
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor Pair where
  fmap f (P x y) = P (f x) (f y)

instance Monad Pair where
  return x = P x x
  P a b >>= f = P x y
    where P x _ = f a
          P _ y = f b

newtype Bad a = B (Maybe (Pair a))
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor Bad where
  fmap f (B x) = B $ fmap (fmap f) x

-- The only definition that could possibly work.
unit :: a -> Bad a
unit x = B (Just (P x x))

-- Number of possible definitions of join for this type. If this equals zero, no monad for you!
joins :: Integer
joins = sum $ do
  -- Try all possible ways of handling cases 3 and 4 in the definition of join below.
  let ways = [ \_ _ -> B Nothing
             , \a b -> B (Just (P a a))
             , \a b -> B (Just (P a b))
             , \a b -> B (Just (P b a))
             , \a b -> B (Just (P b b)) ] :: [forall a. a -> a -> Bad a]
  c3 :: forall a. a -> a -> Bad a <- ways
  c4 :: forall a. a -> a -> Bad a <- ways

  let join :: forall a. Bad (Bad a) -> Bad a
      join (B Nothing) = B Nothing -- no choice
      join (B (Just (P (B Nothing) (B Nothing)))) = B Nothing -- again, no choice
      join (B (Just (P (B (Just (P x1 x2))) (B Nothing)))) = c3 x1 x2
      join (B (Just (P (B Nothing) (B (Just (P x3 x4)))))) = c4 x3 x4
      join (B (Just (P (B (Just (P x1 x2))) (B (Just (P x3 x4)))))) = B (Just (P x1 x4)) -- derived from monad laws

  -- We've already learnt all we can from these two, but I decided to leave them in anyway.
  guard $ all (\x -> join (unit x) == x) bad1
  guard $ all (\x -> join (fmap unit x) == x) bad1

  -- This is the one that matters
  guard $ all (\x -> join (join x) == join (fmap join x)) bad3

  return 1 

main = putStrLn $ show joins ++ " combinations work."

-- Functions for making all the different forms of Bad values containing distinct Ints.

bad1 :: [Bad Int]
bad1 = map fst (bad1' 1)

bad3 :: [Bad (Bad (Bad Int))]
bad3 = map fst (bad3' 1)

bad1' :: Int -> [(Bad Int, Int)]
bad1' n = [(B Nothing, n), (B (Just (P n (n+1))), n+2)]

bad2' :: Int -> [(Bad (Bad Int), Int)]
bad2' n = (B Nothing, n) : do
  (x, n')  <- bad1' n
  (y, n'') <- bad1' n'
  return (B (Just (P x y)), n'')

bad3' :: Int -> [(Bad (Bad (Bad Int)), Int)]
bad3' n = (B Nothing, n) : do
  (x, n')  <- bad2' n
  (y, n'') <- bad2' n'
  return (B (Just (P x y)), n'')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm convinced!  Though it does make me wonder whether there are ways to simplify your proof.

Comment: @BrentYorgey: I suspect there should be, as the problems with cases (C) and (D) seem to be very much like the problems you have when trying to define `swap :: Pair (Maybe a) -> Maybe (Pair a)`.

Comment: So, in short: monads are allowed to throw away information, and that's okay if they're just nested in themselves. But when you have an info-preserving monad and an info-dropping monad, combining the two drops information, even though the info-preserving one *needs* that info kept to satisfy its own monad laws. So you can't combine arbitrary monads.  (This is why you need Traversable monads, which guarantee they won't drop relevant information; they're arbitrarily composable.) Thanks for the intuition!

Comment: @Xanthir Composing works only in one order: `(Maybe a, Maybe a)` is a monad (because it is a product of two monads) but `Maybe (a, a)` is not a monad. I have also verified that `Maybe (a,a)` is not a monad by explicit calculations.

Comment: Mind showing why `Maybe (a, a)` isn't a monad? Both Maybe and Tuple are Traversable, and should be composeable in any order; there are other SO questions that talk about this specific example too.

Answer (score 38):

For a small concrete counterexample, consider the terminal monad.

```
data Thud x = Thud
```

The `return` and `>>=` just go `Thud`, and the laws hold trivially.

Now let's also have the writer monad for Bool (with, let's say, the xor-monoid structure).

```
data Flip x = Flip Bool x

instance Monad Flip where
   return x = Flip False x
   Flip False x  >>= f = f x
   Flip True x   >>= f = Flip (not b) y where Flip b y = f x
```

Er, um, we'll need composition

```
newtype (:.:) f g x = C (f (g x))
```

Now try to define...

```
instance Monad (Flip :.: Thud) where  -- that's effectively the constant `Bool` functor
  return x = C (Flip ??? Thud)
  ...
```

Parametricity tells us that `???` can't depend in any useful way on `x`, so it must be a constant. As a result, `join . return` is necessarily a constant function also, hence the law

```
join . return = id
```

must fail for whatever definitions of `join` and `return` we choose.

Comment: On Carlo's Hamalainen blog there is additional, very clear and detailed analysis of above answer which I've found helpful: http://carlo-hamalainen.net/blog/2014/1/2/applicatives-compose-monads-do-not

Answer (score 35):

### Constructing excluded middle

`(->) r` is a monad for every `r` and `Either e` is a monad for every `e`. Let's define their composition (`(->) r` inside, `Either e` outside):

```
import Control.Monad
newtype Comp r e a = Comp { uncomp :: Either e (r -> a) }
```

I claim that **if `Comp r e` were a monad for every `r` and `e` then we could realize [the law of exluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle)**. This is not possible in [intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic) which underlies typesystems of functional languages (having the law of excluded middle is equivalent to having the [call/cc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) operator).

Let's assume `Comp` is a monad. Then we have

```
join :: Comp r e (Comp r e a) -> Comp r e a
```

and so we can define

```
swap :: (r -> Either e a) -> Either e (r -> a)
swap = uncomp . join . Comp . return . liftM (Comp . liftM return)
```

(This is just the `swap` function from paper *Composing monads* that Brent mentions, Sect. 4.3, only with newtype's (de)constructors added. Note that we don't care what properties it has, the only important thing is that it is definable and total.)

Now let's set

```
data False -- an empty datatype corresponding to logical false
type Neg a = (a -> False) -- corresponds to logical negation
```

and specialize swap for `r = b`, `e = b`, `a = False`:

```
excludedMiddle :: Either b (Neg b)
excludedMiddle = swap Left
```

**Conclusion:** Even though `(->) r` and `Either r` are monads, their composition `Comp r r` cannot be.

Note: That this is also reflected in how [`ReaderT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#t%3aReaderT) and [`EitherT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/EitherT/0.2.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html) are defined. *Both* `ReaderT r (Either e)` and `EitherT e (Reader r)` are isomorphic to `r -> Either e a`! There is no way how to define monad for the dual `Either e (r -> a)`.

---

### Escaping `IO` actions

There are many examples in the same vein that involve `IO` and which lead to escaping `IO` somehow. For example:

```
newtype Comp r a = Comp { uncomp :: IO (r -> a) }

swap :: (r -> IO a) -> IO (r -> a)
swap = uncomp . join . Comp . return . liftM (Comp . liftM return)
```

Now let's have

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   let foo True  = print "First" >> return 1
       foo False = print "Second" >> return 2
   f <- swap foo
   input <- readLn
   print (f input)
```

What will happen when this program is run? There are two possibilities:

1. "First" or "Second" is printed *after* we read `input` from the console, meaning that the sequence of actions was *reversed* and that the actions from `foo` escaped into pure `f`.
2. Or `swap` (hence `join`) throws away the `IO` action and neither "First" nor "Second" is ever printed. But this means that `join` violates the law

   ```
   join . return = id
   ```

   because if `join` throws the `IO` action away, then

   ```
   foo ≠ (join . return) foo
   ```

Other similar `IO` + monad combinations lead to constructing

```
swapEither :: IO (Either e a) -> Either e (IO a)
swapWriter :: (Monoid e) => IO (Writer e a) -> Writer e (IO a)
swapState  :: IO (State e a) -> State e (IO a)
...
```

Either their `join` implementations must allow `e` to escape from `IO` or they must throw it away and replace with something else, violating the law.

Comment: (I suppose "ap" is a typo in "where fmap, pure and ap are the canonical definitions" (should be `<*>` instead), tried to edit it but I was told my edit was too short.)  
---
It's not clear to me that having a definition for `join` implies a definition for `swap`. Could you expand on it? The paper referred by Brent seems to imply that to go from `join` to `swap` we need the following assumptions:

    `joinM . fmapM join = join . joinM` and
    `join . fmap (fmapM joinN ) = fmapM joinN . join`

where joinM = join :: M, etc.

Comment: @RafaelCaetano Thanks for the typo, I fixed it (and also renamed the function to `swap` to match the paper). I didn't check the paper until now, and you're right, looks like we need J(1) and J(2) to define `swap` <-> `join`. This is perhaps a weak spot of my proof and I'll think about it more (maybe it'd be possible to get something from the fact that it's `Applicative`).

Comment: @RafaelCaetano  But I believe the proof is still valid: If we had `join`, we could define `swap :: (Int -> Maybe a) -> Maybe (Int -> a)` using the above definition (no matter what laws this `swap` satisfies). How would such `swap` behave? Having no `Int`, it has nothing to pass to its argument, so it would have to return `Nothing` for all inputs. I believe we can get a contradiction for `join`'s monad laws without needing to define `join` from `swap` back. I'll check it and let you know.

Comment: @Petr: As it stands I agree with Rafael that this is not quite the proof I am looking for, but I am also curious to see whether it can be fixed along the lines you mention.

Comment: @BrentYorgey I'll try to improve it. Do you agree with restating the question as I did? Or do you think that the monad definition of `Bad` may disagree with the default `Applicative`/`Functor` definitions? (In that case I have no idea how/if such an example could be found.)

Comment: @BrentYorgey I worked on it a bit and I came to a surprising conclusion. I updated the proof, check it out.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Wow, very nice!  Yes, I totally buy it now.  These are some really interesting insights.  I would not have guessed that simply *being able to construct* swap could lead to a contradiction, without reference to any of the monad laws at all!  If I could accept multiple answers I would accept this one too.

Comment: Oh, nice. I really like the revised version of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your link references this data type, so let's try picking some specific implementation: `data A3 a = A3 (A1 (A2 a))`

I will arbitrarily pick `A1 = IO, A2 = []`. We'll also make it a `newtype` and give it a particularly pointed name, for fun:

`newtype ListT IO a = ListT (IO [a])`

Let's come up with some arbitrary action in that type, and run it in two different-but-equal ways:

```
λ> let v n = ListT $ do {putStr (show n); return [0, 1]}
λ> runListT $ ((v >=> v) >=> v) 0
0010101[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
λ> runListT $ (v >=> (v >=> v)) 0
0001101[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
```

As you can see, this breaks the associativity law: `∀x y z. (x >=> y) >=> z == x >=> (y >=> z)`.

It turns out, `ListT m` is only a monad if `m` is a *commutative* monad. This prevents a large category of monads from composing with `[]`, which breaks the universal rule of "composing two arbitrary monads yields a monad".

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12617918/1769569

Comment: I would think this only shows that one specific definition of `ListT` fails to produce a monad in all cases, rather than showing that *no possible definition* can work.

Comment: I don't have to. The negation of "for all this, that" is "there exists a counter-example". The question asked was "for all monads, their composition forms a monad". I have shown a combination of types that are monads on their own, but can't compose.

Comment: @hpc, but the composition of two monads is more than the composition of their types.  You also need the operations, and my interpretation of Brent's question is that there may not be a methodical way to derive the implementation of the operations -- he is looking for something yet stronger, that some some compositions have *no* operations satisfying the laws, whether mechanically derivable or not.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, luqui has it right.  Sorry if my original question was not clear.

Comment: What's really missing from this answer is the `Monad` instance for `ListT`, and a demonstration that there aren't any others. The statement is "for all this, there exists that" and so the negation is "there exists this such that for all that"

Answer (score -2):

Monads do not compose. Not in a generic way - there is no general way of composing monads. See https://www.slideshare.net/pjschwarz/monads-do-not-compose