# Can two non-functors compose to a functor?

Tags: haskell, composition, functor, applicative, category-theory

We can have two types `f, g :: * -> *` such that they're not monads, but their composition is. For example for an arbitrary fixed `s`:

```
f a := s -> a
g a := (s, a)
```

`g a` isn't a monad (unless we restrict `s` to a monoid), but `f (g a)` is the state monad `s -> (s, a)`. (Unlike functors and applicative functors, even if both `f` and `g` were monads, [their composition might not be](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13034229/1333025).)

Is there a similar example for functors or applicative functors? That is that the composition of `f` and `g` is a a functor (or an applicative functor), even though

1. one of `f` and `g` isn't an (applicative) functor and the other is, or
2. neither of them is an (applicative) functor,

Comment: The `ContT` transformer makes `Functor`s and `Applicative`s without requiring that the transformed structure is a `Functor`, but isn't built by composition. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#t:ContT Similarly, the free applicative `Ap` adds `Applicative` behavior to any `Functor`, without requiring that it be `Applicative`, but again isn't built by composition. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.9/docs/Control-Applicative-Free.html#t:Ap

Comment: perhaps not an answer but whenever `F` and `G` are adjoint you get a monad in the composition.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a (covariant) functor

```
f x = x -> r
```

but `f . f` is the "continuation" functor (also a monad):

```
f (f x) = (x -> r) -> r
```

This is probably not the best example because `f` is a contravariant functor.

Comment: I'm mainly interested in covariant functors, so I don't mind if `f` is contravariant, the example is fine.

Comment: Do you think it'd be possible to find an example where `f` is a functor but `g` isn't (and `f . g` is)?

Answer (score 7):

Let `g :: *->*`. Then `Const A . g` is a functor for any `A`, in fact isomorphic to `Const A`.

Comment: Trivial base cases make for lame (counter-)examples, but here goes.