# A name for a product of `Const` and a functor?

Tags: haskell, functor

Is `SF` already defined anywhere, or does it at least have a name?

```
data SF a f x = SF a (f x)

instance Functor f => Functor (SF a f) where
  fmap g (SF a fx) = SF a (fmap g fx)
```

Comment: It looks like you are declaring a functor which contains another functor.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't one already out there, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't exist in the corner of some random package I've never used.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I'm defining a functor transformer. `SF a f` is the same as functor `f`, but it carries an additional value of type `a` attached to it.

Comment: (It's isomorphic to a product of `Const a` and `Identity`.)

Comment: @ArtyomKazak Since functors (and applicative functors, [unlike monads](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13034229/1333025)) compose, there is no need for something like (applicative) functor transformer. See `Data.Functor.*` modules in [transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your functor looks like

```
type SF a f = (,) a :. f
```

using [functor-combo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/functor-combo-0.3.5/docs/FunctorCombo-Functor.html#t::.) notation.

(I somehow prefer to look at it using composition, rather than using product and `Const`.)

Comment: A more mainstream name for your `:.` is `Compose` from the `transformer`'s package.

Answer (score 1):

You could just define functor products

```
data (f :* g) a = P (f a) (g a) deriving Functor
```

and then write it directly

```
type SF a f = Const a :* f
```