# Composing Monads v. Applicative Functors

Tags: haskell

The [Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia)'s *Monad Transformers* section explains:

> Unfortunately, monads do not compose as nicely as applicative functors (yet another reason to use Applicative if you don’t need the full power that Monad provides)

Looking at the types of `>>=` and `<*>`, the above statement is not clear to me.

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Please explain the "monads do not compose as nicely as applicative functors."

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040844/applicatives-compose-monads-dont), but could you please give an example to help me understand?

Comment: Since this is under the "Monad Transformers" section, I believe all this means is that `(Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (C f g)` but its not the case that `(Monad f, Monad g) => Monad (C f g)`, where `data C f g a = C (f (g a))`. If you want a deeper understanding of why this is the case, it may be illustrative to try to write the latter instance.

Comment: See also [Concrete example showing that monads are not closed under composition (with proof)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13034229/1333025)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are several notions by which types of kind `* -> *` might "compose". The more important one is you can compose them "sequentially".

```
newtype Compose f g x = Compose { getCompose :: f (g x) }
```

Here you can see that `Compose` has kind `(* -> *) -> (* -> *) -> (* -> *)` much like any good composition of functors ought to.

So the question is: are there law-abiding instances like the following?

```
instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g)
instance (Monad f,       Monad g)       => Monad       (Compose f g)
```

And the short answer as to why monads don't compose as well as applicatives is that while the first instance can be written the second cannot. Let's try!

---

We can warm up with `Functor`

```
instance (Functor f,     Functor g)     => Functor     (Compose f g) where
  fmap f (Compose fgx) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) fgx)
```

Here we see that because we can `fmap` an `fmap`-ed `f` we can pass it through the layers `f` and `g` like we need to. A similar game is played with `pure`

```
instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g) where
  pure a = Compose (pure (pure a))
```

and while `(<*>)` appears tricky, if you look carefully it's the exact same trick we used with both `fmap` and `pure`.

```
  Compose fgf <*> Compose fgx = Compose ((<*>) <$> fgf <*> fgx)
```

In all cases, we can push the operators we need "through" the layers of `f` and `g` exactly as we might hope.

But now let's take a look at `Monad`. Instead of trying to define `Monad` via `(>>=)`, I'm going to instead work via `join`. To implement `Monad` we need to implement

```
join :: Compose f g (Compose f g x) -> Compose f g x
```

using

```
join_f :: f (f x) -> f x  -- and
join_g :: g (g x) -> g x
```

or, if we strip off the `newtype` noise, we need

```
join :: f (g (f (g x))) -> f (g x)
```

At this point it might be clear what the problem is---we only know how to join *consecutive* layers of `f`s or `g`s, but here we see them *interwoven*. What you'll find is that we need a *commutativity* property

```
class Commute f g where
  commute :: g (f x) -> f (g x)
```

and now we can implement

```
instance (Monad f, Monad g, Commute f g) => Monad (Compose f g)
```

with (the `newtype` agnostic) `join` defined as

```
join :: f (g (f (g x))) -> f (g x)
join fgfgx = fgx where
  ffggx :: f (f (g (g x)))
  ffggx = fmap commute fgfgx
  fggx :: f (g (g x))
  fggx = join_f ffggx
  fgx :: f (g x)
  fgx = fmap join_g fggx
```

---

So what's the upshot of all this? `Applicative`s *always* `Compose`, but `Monad`s `Compose` only when their layers `Commute`.

When can we `commute` layers? Here are some examples

```
instance Commute ((->) x) ((->) y) where
  commute = flip

instance Commute ((,) x) ((,) y) where
  commute (y, (x, a)) = (x, (y, a))

instance Commute ((->) x) ((,) y) where
  commute (y, xa) = \x -> (y, xa x)

-- instance Commute ((,) x) ((->) y) does not exist; try to write yourself!
--
-- OR:
-- It turns out that you need to somehow "travel back in time" to make it
-- work...
-- 
-- instance Commute ((,) x) ((->) y) where
--   commute yxa = ( ..., \y -> let (x, a) = yxa y in a )
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning, that since the `Traversable` type class provides the `sequence` function, which has this type signature: `sequence :: Monad m => t (m a) -> m (t a)`, you can define `NestedMonads` as `type NestedMonads m t = (Monad m, Traversable t, Monad t)` and then `bibind :: NestedMonads m t => m (t a) -> (a -> m (t b)) -> m (t b)`. The [code](http://lpaste.net/130180).

Comment: That gives a good intuition as to what `Commute` might do as well, thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to add here that `Traversable` doesn't appear to be the correct constraint on the inner monad. See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42298943/2684007).