# For Comprehension Example to Understand Composing Monads

Tags: scala, monads

[J. Abrahamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476408/j-abrahamson) provided an in-depth answer to my [composing-monads-v-applicative-functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453915/composing-monads-v-applicative-functors) question.

I gained some intuition, but I do not fully understand his helpful answer.

Given the following `Either`'s:

```
scala> x
res0: Either[String,Int] = Right(100)

scala> err
res1: Either[Boolean,Int] = Left(false)
```

I tried to chain them together:

```
scala> for {
     |   xx <- x.right
     |   yy <- err.right
     | } yield xx + yy
res3: scala.util.Either[Any,Int] = Left(false)
```

But, of course I don't want an `Either[Any, Int]`. Yet we get `Any` since, as I understand, the parent of `Either[String, Int]` and `Either[Boolean, Int]` is `Either[Any, Int]`.

When building a for-comprehension, is the typical approach to find an end-type, i.e. `Either[String, Int]`, and then make each `flatMap` call have that type?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want `Either[Boolean, Int]` instead of `Either[Any, Int]`, then "You can't always get what you want". Composition of same (as in your example) `Either` types (but some other values) may return `String` instead of `Boolean` even for right projection:

```
scala> val x: Either[String,Int] = Left("aaa")
x: Either[String,Int] = Left(aaa)

scala> val r: Either[Boolean,Int] = Right(100)
r: Either[Boolean,Int] = Right(100)

scala> for {
     |    xx <- x.right
     |    yy <- r.right //you may swap xx and yy - it doesn't matter for this example, which means that flatMap could be called on any of it         
     | } yield yy + xx
res21: scala.util.Either[Any,Int] = Left(aaa)
```

So, `Either[Any,Int]` is really correct and smaller as possible end-type for it.

The desugared version:

```
scala> x.right.flatMap(xx => r.right.map(_ + xx))
res27: scala.util.Either[Any,Int] = Left(aaa)
```

Monad's `flatMap` signature:

```
flatMap[AA >: A, Y](f: (B) ⇒ Either[AA, Y]): Either[AA, Y]
```

Passed types:

```
flatMap[Any >: String, Int](f: (Int) ⇒ Either[?Boolean?, Int]): Either[Any, String]
```

`AA >: A` is completely legal here as it allows `f = r.right.map(_ + xx)` return left type bigger than `String` (so `?Boolean?` becomes `Any`), otherwise it wouldn't even work. Answering your question, `flatMap` can't have `AA = Boolean` here, because `A` is already at least `String`, and as shown in first example can actually be a `String`.

And, by the way, there is no monads composition in this example - `r` could be just a functor. More than that, you're composing `RightProjection` with `RightProjection` here, so they commute automatically.

The only way to inferr `Boolean` is to kill `String` type with `Nothing` - you can do that only if you sure that `x` is always `Right`:

```
scala> val x: Either[Nothing,Int] = Right(100)
x: Either[Nothing,Int] = Right(100)

scala> val r: Either[Boolean,Int] = Left(false)
r: Either[Boolean,Int] = Left(false)

scala> for {
     |    yy <- r.right
     |    xx <- x.right  
     |        
     | } yield yy + xx
res24: scala.util.Either[Boolean,Int] = Left(false)
```

Then, of course you can't put strings, which is totally correct.