# Haskell's mapM when there are 3 monadic results

Tags: haskell, monads, persistent

Now and again I keep running into Haskell code where I feel like I should be able to use `mapM` to make operating over the monads cleaner, but if I have two computations of type `m (t a)`, and perhaps there is another operation that uses `t`, something like `a -> t a` (typically this is `Maybe`)... say I have this persistent code:

```
findDealership :: MonadIO m => Key Vehicle -> SqlPersistT m (Maybe (Entity Dealership))
findDealership vehicleKey = mapM selectDealership (getVehicleDealership vehicleKey)

getVehicleDealership :: MonadIO m => Key Vehicle -> SqlPersistT m (Maybe (Key Dealership))
getVehicleDealership vehicleKey =
  (\x -> x >>= vehicleDealershipId . entityVal) <$> getEntity vehicleKey

selectDealership :: MonadIO m => Key Dealership -> SqlPersistT m (Maybe (Entity Dealership))
selectDealership dealershipKey = selectFirst [DealershipId ==. dealershipKey] []
```

Where `vehicleDealershipId` is a field of type `Maybe (Key Dealership)`, the above code will not compile and I'm unable to work out the right combination of `>>=`'s and `mapM`'s.... I feel this problem is a bit like the one `mapM` is solving, only there is another level of monad in there... you can end up with `SqlPersistT m (Maybe (Maybe (Maybe (Key Dealership))))` but obviously I need the inner type to be completely flattened...

Error output for the above code:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
                             SqlBackend m0’
                     with ‘Maybe’
      Expected type: SqlPersistT m (Maybe (Entity Dealership))
        Actual type: Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
                       SqlBackend
                       m
                       (Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
                          SqlBackend m0 (Maybe (Entity Dealership)))
    • In the expression:
        mapM selectDealership $ getVehicleDealership vehicleKey
      In an equation for ‘findDealership’:
          findDealership vehicleKey
            = mapM selectDealership $ getVehicleDealership vehicleKey
   |
46 | findDealership vehicleKey = mapM selectDealership $ getVehicleDealership vehicleKey
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Maybe (Key Dealership)’
                     with ‘Key Dealership’
      Expected type: Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
                       SqlBackend m0 (Key Dealership)
        Actual type: SqlPersistT m0 (Maybe (Key Dealership))
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘getVehicleDealership vehicleKey’
      In the expression:
        mapM selectDealership $ getVehicleDealership vehicleKey
      In an equation for ‘findDealership’:
          findDealership vehicleKey
            = mapM selectDealership $ getVehicleDealership vehicleKey
   |
46 | findDealership vehicleKey = mapM selectDealership $ getVehicleDealership vehicleKey
   |                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the error?

Comment: What's `t` when it isn't a `Maybe`?  Is it intended to be any `Traversable`?  If so, then this seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189135/compose-nested-monads-in-haskell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have come to realise now, is that what I wanted here was `MaybeT`.

My example can be re-written using `MaybeT` like so:

```
findDealership :: MonadIO m => Key Vehicle -> SqlPersistT m (Maybe (Entity Dealership))
findDealership vehicleKey = runMaybeT $ do
  dealershipKey <- MaybeT (getVehicleDealership vehicleKey) 
  selectDealership dealershipKey

getVehicleDealership :: MonadIO m => Key Vehicle -> SqlPersistT m (Maybe (Key Dealership))
getVehicleDealership vehicleKey = runMaybeT $ do
  vehicleEntity <- MaybeT (getEntity vehicleKey)
  hoistMaybe $ vehicleDealershipId (entityVal vehicleEntity)

selectDealership :: MonadIO m => Key Dealership -> SqlPersistT m (Maybe (Entity Dealership))
selectDealership dealershipKey = 
  selectFirst [DealershipId ==. dealershipKey] []
```

Answer (score 3):

When you want to flatten several `Maybe`s, you can use `join`.  It works for any `Monad`, but comes up most often for `Maybe`.

```
getVehicleDealership :: MonadIO m => Key Vehicle -> SqlPersistT m (Maybe (Key Dealership))
getVehicleDealership vehicleKey =
    join . fmap (vehicleDealershipId . entityVal) <$> getEntity vehicleKey
```

`mapM` (AKA `traverse`) is useful in many situations, but I don't think it applies here.  It doesn't matter which order the `Maybe`s appear, and you want `SqlPersistT m (Maybe a)`, not `Maybe (SqlPersistT m a)`.