# Creating a Monad Transformer from a Monad

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Given an arbitrary monad, is there a way to create a monad transformer based on that monad? I googled this question and didn't see anywhere where it was addressed (although I may have missed it) so I just tried to do it myself, and I got close, I think:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (MonadTrans, lift)

newtype ToMonadTrans m2 m1 a = ToMonadTrans (m2 (m1 a))

instance (Functor m2, Functor m1) => Functor (ToMonadTrans m2 m1) where
  fmap f (ToMonadTrans x) = ToMonadTrans (fmap (fmap f) x)

instance (Applicative m2, Applicative m1) => Applicative (ToMonadTrans m2 m1) where
  pure = ToMonadTrans . pure . pure
  ToMonadTrans f <*> ToMonadTrans x = ToMonadTrans (((<*>) . (fmap (<*>))) f x)

instance (Monad m2, Monad m1) => Monad (ToMonadTrans m2 m1) where
  ToMonadTrans x >>= ToMonadTrans f = ToMonadTrans (???)

instance Monad m2 => MonadTrans (ToMonadTrans m2) where
  lift x = ToMonadTrans (pure x)
```

The idea here is that `ToMonadTrans Maybe` is the same as `MaybeT`. The good thing about this approach (if it works) is that you can make any monad into a `MonadTrans`, allowing one to layer any monad without having to write a corresponding specialised transformer.

As you can see, I implemented `MonadTrans` as well as `Functor` and `Applicative`, the only place I got stuck is `Monad`.

My questions are:

1. Can this be done?
2. Has this been done in a package on hackage?

Comment: `ToMonadTrans` is isomorphic to `Compose`. In general cases, the composition of two monads is not a monad. Monad Transformers are just able to somehow do these compositions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453915/composing-monads-v-applicative-functors http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/monads-do-not-compose/

Comment: Could you use [FreeT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-free-1.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free.html#g:3)?

Comment: You cannot do this in general. There is no algorithmic way of taking a definition of a monad (e.g., type and code in Haskell) and producing the type and code of the corresponding transformer. There are at least 4 different classes of monads whose transformers are constructed in completely different ways (composed-inside, composed-outside, adjunction monad, product monad), and there are a few other monads that do not belong to any of these 4 classes.