# Monad Transformer: troubles defining bind due to different monads

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

I have a Monad of named `TaskMonad`, defined as follows:

```
data TaskMonad a = TaskMonad (Environment -> (TaskResult a, Environment))
```

where `Environment` is a record type and `TaskResult` is an ADT; but they are not important for the problem.

I have defed `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` instances for `TaskMonad`, and I now want to be able to combine this monad with other Monads (e.g. `IO`), So I defined a new type as follows:

```
newtype Task m a = Task { runTask :: m (TaskMonad a) }
```

I have defined `Functor` and `Applicative` as follows:

```
instance Monad m => Functor (Task m) where
    fmap f ta = Task $ do tma <- runTask ta
                          return (fmap f tma)

instance Monad m => Applicative (Task m) where
    pure = Task . return . return
    (<*>) prod tx = Task $ do tmprod <- runTask prod
                              tmtx   <- runTask tx
                              return (tmprod <*> tmtx)
```

And I also made `Task` member of the `MonadTrans` class:

```
instance MonadTrans Task where
    lift = Task . (liftM return)
```

So far so good (or atleast it compiles..), but now I want to define the instance for `Monad`, but I am running into problems here:

```
instance Monad m => Monad (Task m) where
    return      = pure
    (>>=) ta tb = ...
```

I attempted multiple things, most attempts starting out like this:

```
(>>=) ta tb = Task $ do tma <- runTask ta
```

Now we have `tma :: TaskMonad a` inside the `do` block for the `m` monad. Now what I would like to do, is somehow calling the `>>=` instance for `TaskMonad` so I can get the result of `tma`, a value of type `a` so I can parameterize `tb` with it to obtain a value of `Task b`. But I am within the context of the `m` monad and I'm running into all kinds of problems.

How could I obtain `tma`'s result to provide it to `tb`?

Comment: an obvious problem will be that you don't get an `Environment` right? I think you have to break open `TaskMonad` again (instead of using the `>>=` you already got)

Comment: Uh oh, after many bad words spoken I got my instance of Applicative for TaskMonad to work. I'm getting rusty. Trying to get your bind to work now.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I will have to fiddle with the `Environment` a bit indeed. Important to note is that the `(>>=)` function for `TaskMonad` is somewhat complex; simply providing an `Environment` to a `TaskMonad` is not sufficient. I need it to be expressed using `TaskMonad`'s `(>>=)`. Thanks for trying Bartek! I'm out of bad words myself by now.

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to define `TaskMonad` as a transformer from the very beginning? It looks similar to StateT on the outside, perhaps this is the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I don't know how much this helps, but if you actually start with a transformer from day 0 (in `TaskMonad`), the way you can do it is:

```
data TaskMonad m a = TaskMonad (Environment -> m (TaskResult a, Environment)) deriving Functor
        
instance Monad m => Monad (TaskMonad m) where
    return = pure
    (TaskMonad f) >>= b = TaskMonad $ \e -> do
        (TaskResult r, e') <- f e
        let (TaskMonad g) = b r
        g e'

instance (Monad m, Functor m) => Applicative (TaskMonad m) where
    pure a = TaskMonad $ \e -> return (TaskResult a, e)
    (TaskMonad f) <*> (TaskMonad g) = TaskMonad $ \e -> do
        (TaskResult f', e') <- f e 
        (TaskResult a, e'') <- g e'
        return (TaskResult (f' a), e'')
```

Probably there's also a way to do that the way you originally intended, but I am pretty sure original `Task` would also need to be changed to take initial `Environment`.

I presume you're actually doing more than `State` in your monad, so that would need to be put in respective instances, but I think the framework for that should help.

And of course, shall you ever need to use a non-transformer version, just pass in `Identity` for `m`.

---

#### Disclaimer:

I know this implemenation of `Applicative` instance doesn't make sense, but I was building that on old GHC w/o `ApplicativeDo` and it was literally the easiest thing to put the silly constraint there.

Comment: It's possible to define just `(<*>) = ap`.

Answer (score 2):

As described in @BartekBanachewicz's answer, putting the monad `m` inside `->` is the way to go.

I believe it's not possible to do it the way you want by having `m (TaskMonad a)`, at least not generically. In general [monads aren't closed under composition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13034229/1333025) and this is an example of such a situation.

Let me give a simplified example (some theory will be required for it): Let's work with the reader monad instead of the state monad, let's drop `TaskResult` and let's have the environment as a type parameter. So `TaskMonad` will be just `m (r -> a)`. Now let's assume it's a monad, then there is

```
join :: m (r -> (m (r -> a))) -> m (r -> a)
```

Specializing `a` to [`Void`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.7.1/docs/Data-Void.html) (see also [Bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type)) and `m` to `Either r` we get

```
join :: Either r (r -> (Either r (r -> Void))) -> Either r (r -> Void)
```

But then we're able to construct

```
doubleNegationElimination :: Either r (r -> Void)
doubleNegationElimination = join (Right Left)
```

as `Right Left :: Either r (r -> Either r (r -> Void))`. Through [Curry-Howard isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) this would mean that we'd be able to prove [Double negation elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation#Double_negative_elimination)
 in intuitionistic logic, which is a contradiction.

Your situation is somewhat more complex, but a similar argument could be made there too. The only hole there is that we assumed that the "environment" part, `r`, was generic, so won't work if your `join` or `>>=` is somehow specific for `Environment`. So you might be able to do it in such a case, but my guess is you'll then encounter other problems preventing you to get a proper non-trivial `Monad` instance.