# How to chain a -> IO (m b) functions

Tags: haskell, types, monads

There are functions with signatures like:

```
a -> IO (m b)
b -> IO (m c)
c -> IO (m d)
```

How do I chain them in

```
a -> IO (m d)
```

?

Practical application: say there a set of REST endpoints. Each of the return a value and next one is requires the value returned by previous as an argument.

So functions for fetching from the endpoints are like:

```
Value1 -> IO (Maybe Value2)
Value2 -> IO (Maybe Value3)
Value3 -> IO (Maybe Value4)
```

Comment: You are looking for Kliesli composition `(>=>)` Check here http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-

Comment: Additionally `IO (Maybe a) ~ MaybeT IO a` and `MaybeT` is defined in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#v:MaybeT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There are functions with signatures like:
>
> ```
> a -> IO (m b)
> b -> IO (m c)
> c -> IO (m d)
> ```
>
> How do I chain them in
>
> ```
> a -> IO (m d)
> ```

In general, you might not be able to. For example, if `m` is [`Const`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Const.html#t:Const), I'm not sure asking this even makes sense. In general, you probably expect `m` to be a `Monad`. However, note that even if `m` *is* a `Monad`, its composition with `IO` may not be ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034229/concrete-example-showing-that-monads-are-not-closed-under-composition-with-proo)).

> ```
> Value1 -> IO (Maybe Value2)
> Value2 -> IO (Maybe Value3)
> Value3 -> IO (Maybe Value4)
> ```

Ah, Now you are talking! The abstraction you are looking for here is [`MaybeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#t:MaybeT) and Kleisli composition [`(>=>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-). Then, for example,

```
import Control.Monad ((>=>))
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (MaybeT(..))

rest1 :: Value1 -> IO (Maybe Value2)
rest2 :: Value2 -> IO (Maybe Value3)
rest3 :: Value3 -> IO (Maybe Value4)

rest4 :: Value1 -> IO (Maybe Value4)
rest4 x = runMaybeT ((MaybeT . rest1 >=> MaybeT . rest2 >=> MaybeT . rest3) x)
```

That still looks a bit ugly. The thing to do is probably to refactor your `rest1`, `rest2`, and `rest3` functions. As has been pointed out in the comments `MaybeT IO a` can be converted to and from `IO (Maybe a)` (in fact that is exactly what `runMaybeT` and `MaybeT` do).

```
import Control.Monad ((>=>))
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (MaybeT(..))

rest1 :: Value1 -> MaybeT IO Value2
rest2 :: Value2 -> MaybeT IO Value3
rest3 :: Value3 -> MaybeT IO Value4

rest4 :: Value1 -> MaybeT IO Value4
rest4 = rest1 >=> rest2 >=> rest3
```

Comment: After refactoring, would it make sense to regeneralize the `rest` functions, to recapture the flavor of the original functions? E.g., `rest1 :: MonadTrans mt => Value1 -> mt IO Value2`?

Comment: @chepner I would definitely say yes; though I'm not sure your particular type makes sense. Something like `rest1 :: (MonadIO m, MonadPlus m) => Value1 -> m Value2` would express that `rest1` may do some IO (`MonadIO`) and may not succeed (`MonadPlus`).

Answer (score 2):

if m has an instance of `Traversable` (`Maybe` has one) here is another alternative:

```
import           Control.Monad (join)

f :: (Traversable m, Monad m)
  => (a -> IO (m b))
  -> (b -> IO (m c))
  -> (c -> IO (m d))
  -> a
  -> IO (m d)
f fa fb fc a = fa a
           >>= traverse fb
           >>= fmap join . traverse fc . join
```

Comment: Looks like you don’t need the `liftIO`, and `>>= return . join` is `fmap join`.

Comment: for the part with `>>= return . join` I wanted to separate the final step. so if one wanted to add more steps (ie.  `d -> IO (m e)` )  to this example, they would just add another line with `>>= traverse fd . join` before the last line.