# What does one gain when redefining data constructors, and in place of what expressions might such a definition be substituted?

Tags: haskell

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13042792/2108477), I'm getting puzzled by the very first code fragment:

```
data Pair a = P a a

instance Functor Pair where
  fmap f (P x y) = P (f x) (f y)

instance Monad Pair where
  return x = P x x

  P a b >>= f = P x y
    where P x _ = f a
          P _ y = f b
```

What I see is the author **redefining a data constructor** *two times* and ***applying it to undefined variables***.

First off, how does the second of the two definitions of `P` (those two that are found in the `where` clause of the `instance Monad` definition) matter if, as I believe, the first one (whichever we put first) always matches?

Second, according to what syntax rules could the expression `P x y` get evaluated when there are no expressions for `x` and `y` in scope, but rather some kind of a *redefinition of a data constructor* that *happens to mention these variables' names*?

Interesting to note that, if I instead write like:

```
  P a b >>= f = P x y
    where P u _ = f a
          P _ v = f b
```

— substituting `u` & `v` for `x` & `y` 
— I will observe an `error: Variable not in scope` for each of `x` & `y`, even though by all sane intuition renaming a bound variable makes no difference.

Comment: Those are no *redefinitions* of `P` but a simple pattern match on the result of the call to `f`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equation

```
P x y = z
```

does not define `P`, only `x` and `y`. This is the case in general: only the `data` and `newtype` keywords can introduce new constructors. All other equations define only term variables. To disambiguate between the two, constructors always begin with upper case (for the special case of operators, `:` counts as "upper case punctuation") and variables always begin with lower case.

So, the meaning of

```
P a b >>= f = P x y
  where P x _ = f a
        P _ y = f b
```

reads like this:

1. Define a new function named `(>>=)`. It is defined when the first argument matches the pattern `P a b` (binding `a` and `b` to the actual values `P` is applied to in the first argument), and when the second argument matches the pattern `f` (that is, always, and binding `f` to the value of that second argument).
2. Apply `f` to `a`. Make sure the result of this matches the pattern `P x _` (binding `x` to the first value `P` is applied to and throwing away the second).
3. Apply `f` to `b`. Make sure the result of this matches the pattern `P _ y` (binding `y` to the second value `P` is applied to and throwing away the first).
4. Return the value `P x y`.

Comment: You can also desugar this to `case` statements: `P a b >>= f = case f a of P x _ -> case f b of P _ y -> P x y`

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky, not precisely. The given code uses a lazy pattern match, which may or may not be significant.