# Scala: SeqT monad transformer?

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

If we have such two functions...

```
def findUserById(id: Long): Future[Option[User]] = ???
def findAddressByUser(user: User): Future[Option[Address]] = ???
```

...then we are able to use cats `OptionT` monad transformer to write for-comprehension with them easily:

```
for {
  user    <- OptionT(findUserById(id))
  address <- OptionT(findAddressByUser(user))
} ...
```

I'd like to compose future of sequences this way, like this:

```
def findUsersBySomeField(value: FieldValue): Future[Seq[User]] = ???
def findAddressesByUser(user: User): Future[Seq[Address]] = ???

for {
  user    <- SeqT(findUsersBySomeField(value))
  address <- SeqT(findAddressesByUser(user))
} ...
```

But I can't find any `SeqT` implementation in Cats or Scalaz. Does some implementation of such monad transformer exist or I need to write monad transformer myself? Not that it too hard, just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

(example at the beginning of my question is brought from [this article](https://blog.buildo.io/monad-transformers-for-the-working-programmer-aa7e981190e7))

Comment: Scalaz has `ListT`. Cats had nothing like that last time I checked (which was 0.9.0)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617916/why-is-listt-monad-transformer-considered-buggy-what-monad-laws-it-breaks

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz, linked question is about monad transformer from Haskell standard library. My question is about Scala. How can this link be helpful for me here?

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov thanks, it helped! You could post it as answer.

Comment: The same problems in Haskell also apply to Scala. Here's a link to the issue in the scalaz repo: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/issues/921

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz they write that ListT works only if argument monad is commutative. But Future IS commutative monad, am I right? So, I can use ListT in my case.

Thanks for the tip, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cats, as of 1.0.0-MF have nothing of sorts. That is explained at [their FAQ](https://typelevel.github.io/cats/faq.html#listt):

> A naive implementation of `ListT` suffers from associativity issues; see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tpolecat/1227e22e3161b5816e014c00650f3b57) for an example. It's possible to create a `ListT` that doesn't have these issues, but it tends to be pretty inefficient. For many use-cases, [Nested](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/Nested.scala) can be used to achieve the desired results.

Scalaz, as of 7.2.15 has `StreamT` and `ListT`, although the latter [has](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/issues/921) associativity issues.