# Can monad with broken associativity law yield incorrect result in for-comprehension?

Tags: scala, monads, for-comprehension, associativity

Here is a `Monad` instance for `ListT` (copied from [montrivo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60405778/5205022))

```
case class ListT[M[_], A](value: M[List[A]])
implicit def listTMonad[M[_]: Monad] = new Monad[ListT[M, *]] {
  override def flatMap[A, B](fa: ListT[M, A])(f: A => ListT[M, B]): ListT[M, B] =
    ListT(
      Monad[M].flatMap[List[A], List[B]](fa.value)(
        list => Traverse[List].flatTraverse[M, A, B](list)(a => f(a).value)
      )
    )
  override def pure[A](a: A): ListT[M, A] = ListT(Monad[M].pure(List(a)))
  override def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: A => ListT[M, Either[A, B]]): ListT[M, B] = ???
}
```

It does [not](https://gist.github.com/tpolecat/1227e22e3161b5816e014c00650f3b57) satisfy [associativity](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/demystifying-the-monad-in-scala-cc716bb6f534#0b26) monad law

```
val a: Int => ListT[List, Int] = {
  case 0 => ListT(List(List(0, 1)))
  case 1 => ListT(List(List(0), List(1)))
}
assert(a(0).flatMap(a).flatMap(a) != a(0).flatMap(x ⇒ a(x).flatMap(a)), "Associativity law is not satisfied")
```

because, although we get the same values, they are in different order

```
ListT(List(List(0, 1, 0, 0, 1), List(0, 1, 1, 0, 1), List(0, 1, 0, 0), List(0, 1, 0, 1), List(0, 1, 1, 0), List(0, 1, 1, 1)))
ListT(List(List(0, 1, 0, 0, 1), List(0, 1, 0, 0), List(0, 1, 0, 1), List(0, 1, 1, 0, 1), List(0, 1, 1, 0), List(0, 1, 1, 1)))
```

However it seem to work correctly in for-comprehensions (in my personal project). Generally, is it safe to use "monads" that brake associativity law in for-comprehensions? Could you provide a counter-example demonstrating incorrect result?

Comment: a good read https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348692/why-associativity-h-circ-g-circ-f-h-circ-g-circ-f-is-required-in-com/1348702

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `for`-comprehensions are syntactic sugar for `flatMap` (and `map`), it definitely is the case that a broken `flatMap` could result in incorrect `for`-comprehension code. For example:

```
import cats.{Monad, Traverse}, cats.implicits._

// Your code here...

val first = for {
  y <- for {
    x <- a(0)
    y <- a(x)
  } yield y
  z <- a(y)
} yield z

val second = for {
  x <- a(0)
  y <- a(x)
  z <- a(y)
} yield z
```

And then:

```
scala> first == second
res0: Boolean = false
```

This is your example rewritten to use `for`-comprehensions instead of `flatMap` directly (there are also some extra `map` operations at the end here, but that's an implementation detail and not really relevant).

As a side note, I'm not sure "is it safe?" is exactly the best way to phrase this question. If your `for`-comprehensions in `ListT` produce the correct result—and they definitely might, even though `ListT`'s `flatMap` isn't associative—then in a sense they're "safe".

What lawfulness gives you is the ability to perform certain kinds of rewriting with confidence, and to be able to know at a glance that expressions have the same value (e.g. `a(0).flatMap(a).flatMap(a)` and `a(0).flatMap(a(_).flatMap(a))`), without having to look into the implementations of the methods they use. This is what you're missing because `ListT` doesn't have an associative `flatMap`. Whether that counts as "safe" or not is a judgment call you have to make.